# Haskell partial application doesn't seem to work with on. Why?

Tags: haskell

Partially applying on with a single other function seems to change the types involved.

Starting with on compare length "aaa" "bb" and peeling off items from the right, things start off predictable:

```
Prelude Data.Function> :t on compare length "aaa" "bb"
on compare length "aaa" "bb" :: Ordering

Prelude Data.Function> on compare length "aaa" "bb"
GT


Prelude Data.Function> :t on compare length "aaa"
on compare length "aaa" :: [Char] -> Ordering

Prelude Data.Function> let ocla = on compare length "aaa"

Prelude Data.Function> :t ocla
ocla :: [Char] -> Ordering

Prelude Data.Function> ocla "aa"
GT


Prelude Data.Function> :t on compare length
on compare length :: [a] -> [a] -> Ordering

Prelude Data.Function> let ocl = on compare length

Prelude Data.Function> :t ocl
ocl :: [a] -> [a] -> Ordering

Prelude Data.Function> ocl "aaa" "aa"
GT
```

But with on compare I got a surprise:

```
Prelude Data.Function> :t on compare
on compare :: Ord b => (a -> b) -> a -> a -> Ordering

Prelude Data.Function> let oc = on compare

Prelude Data.Function> :t oc
oc :: (a -> ()) -> a -> a -> Ordering

Prelude Data.Function> oc length "aaa" "aa"

<interactive>:27:4:
    Couldn't match type `Int' with `()'
    Expected type: [Char] -> ()
      Actual type: [Char] -> Int
    In the first argument of `oc', namely `length'
    In the expression: oc length "aaa" "aa"
    In an equation for `it': it = oc length "aaa" "aa"
```

Why is the type of oc not the same as the type of on compare?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because of the dreaded Monomorphism restriction.  GHCi uses the Monomorphism restriction to guess the simplest possible type for a function or value defined in interactive mode.  This is usually very useful, but quite often it is dumb and picks `()` where you really want a typeclass restrained type, like `Ord a => a`.  Just provide your `oc` function a type signature and you'll be fine:

```
let oc :: Ord b => (a -> b) -> a -> a -> Ordering; oc = on compare
```

You can turn off the Monomorphism restriction if you'd like with `:set -XNoMonomorphismRestriction` (thanks @Xeo), but I would recommend against it.  Either put your functions in a file and load them into GHCi, or add type signatures in interactive mode.

---

The wiki article at http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monomorphism_restriction explains this problem in more detail.

Comment: Or go with `:set -XNoMonomorphismRestriction` for GHCi.

Comment: To be precise, it's the monomorphism restriction in combination with `ExtendedDefaultRules`. The former forces a monomorphic type. The latter causes GHCi to pick `()` instead of reporting an error.

Comment: @kosmikus TIL.  I'll be sure to mention that next time this question pops up.

Comment: This is why GHCi 7.8 is still has -XNoMonomorphismRestriction by default iirc

Comment: Why would you recommend against it? There's not much of a reason for `NoMonomorphismRestriction` in source files because a top level type signature is usually enough to fix any problems that arise from the monomorphism restriction, but there's no real harm in it when using it in GHCi (at least none that would justify the additional overhead for every declaration that would arise when doing what you proposed).

Comment: @Cubic I would recommend checking out [this](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monomorphism_restriction) article on it.  It is fairly controversial on whether it should be on by default or not, and the difference is subtle.  My main reasoning is that having it on encourages type signatures even in interactive mode, which are easy if you enable multi-line definitions with `:set +m` or wrap it in `:{` and `:}`.

Comment: I know that article. The problem is that I don't want to have to write type signatures in interactive mode. I do occasionally when it's helpful, but usually I use interactive sessions for quickly trying things out. That's kind of the point of having an interactive mode. Extra typing doesn't help there.

Comment: @Cubic That is a common use case, I often use it for testing code I've written in a file already or for asking the type of an expression using `:t`, but I come across enough instances where a specific type signature is actually needed that I've gotten in the habit of specifying them for any function that uses anything beyond `Prelude`.

Comment: @bheklilr Thanks for your answer.  I just tried "oc = on compare" in a file and it wouldn't compile without a type signature, because its type was ambiguous.  The haskell.org wiki article is worth putting in the answer itself imho.

Comment: @IvanUemlianin I added the link to my answer so that others will find it more easily, thanks for the suggestion!